# Searching for a string in an array

Tags: c++, arrays, string, search, struct

I have "items" in an "inventory" array, the inventory array is a struct composed of several different parts however I want to be able to search for a certain part of the array by using the item name alone (so I can make functions to delete, purchase, etc.) I was wondering how I would go about doing so and if it would instead be easier to convert the struct to a class instead if need be. Keep in mind a good amount of it is still a work in progress, I'm specifically aiming for the removeItem function currently however. Thanks in advance for any and all help!

my code is here:

```
#include "integerstore.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void removeItem(Item);
int buyItem(Item, int);
int sellItem(Item, int);
void stockReport(Item);

struct Item
{
string name;
float cost;
float price;
int quantity;
};

int main()
{
Item inventory[100];
int total = 0;
string cmd;

cout << "Welcome to inventory management. To add a new inventory item type add, to remove and item from inventory type remove, to add to inventory quantity type buy, to mark a sold item type sell, to see the current inventory report type report and to end the program type stop" << endl;

do
{
    cin >> cmd;

    if (cmd == "add") 
    {
        cout << "Enter the new item's name";
        cin >> inventory[i].name;
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the new item's cost";
        cin >> inventory[i].cost;
        if (inventory[i].cost <= 100.00)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Cost of item may not exceed 100.00, please reenter.";
            cin.clear();
        }
        cout << endl;
        cout << "Enter the new item's selling price";
        cin >> inventory[i].price;
        if (inventory[i].price <= 100.00)
        {
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            cout << "Selling price may not exceed 100.00, please reenter.";
            cin.clear();
        }
        cout << endl;
        i++;
    }
    else if (cmd == "remove") 
        removeItem(inventory[100]);

    else if (cmd == "buy") 
        buyItem(inventory[100], total);

    else if (cmd == "sell") 
        sellItem(inventory[100]);

    else if (cmd == "report") 
        stockReport(inventory[100]);

    else if (cmd != "stop") 
        cout << "invalid";
}
while (cmd != "stop");

system ("pause");
return 0;
}


int buyItem(Item w, int w2)
{
string itemName;
cout << "Enter the item name of which you wish to add more stock to" << endl;
cin >> itemName;


}

int sellItem(Item x, int x2)
{

}

void removeItem (Item y)
{
string itemName;
cout << "Enter the item name you wish to remove from the inventory" << endl;
cin >> itemName;
}


void stockReport(Item z)
{

}
```

Comment: Instead of array, why not use map with string name as key?

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [`map<string, Item>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) (you might want to remove `name` from the `Item` struct).

Then you can use it for instance like this:

```
map<string, Item> inventory;
// Add
inventory["stuff"].cost = 12;
// ...
// Get
string name;
cin >> name;
Item myItem = inventory[name];
```